# ajaxsubmit target form input field

Tags: jquery, ajax, input-field

I'm trying to figure out if ajaxSubmit is only able to target #div's or also other objects.

I have a script which uploads an image with ajax, and afer uploading the url of the image will be shown in a #div called Output. However, I want this url visible in an input field, not in a div.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#UploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#SubmitButton').attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
            //show uploading message
            $("#output").html('<div style="padding:10px"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Please Wait"/> <span>Uploading...</span></div>');
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                target: '#output',
                success:  afterSuccess //call function after success
            });
        });
    }); 

    function afterSuccess()  { 
        $('#UploadForm').resetForm();  // reset form
        $('#SubmitButton').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button

    } 
</script>
```

So is it possible to target the name of the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function afterSuccess(url){
        $('#UploadForm').resetForm();  // reset form
        $('#SubmitButton').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
        $('#output').append('input').addClass('myCssClass').val(url);
}
```

Comment: the input field is not within the #output div.

Comment: this way it will be created inside output. if you dont want that, just reference the input field directly
 $('#yourInputId').val(url); in afterSuccess (replace last line)

Comment: so in my form I should have <input type='text' id='test' /> and I should put $('#test').val(url); ? I tried something similar but I didn't work. Should I add a value='' to the input?

Comment: no need to add value attribute. It will be added. Did you place the code right after $('#SubmitButton').removeAttr....
Before adding the line, add a console.log or an alert to see if the url value is there: alert(url); if you then do $('#test').val(url); it should definitely work

Comment: I put it like you said, but I don't see an alert!

function afterSuccess()  { 
   $('#UploadForm').resetForm();  // reset form
   $('#SubmitButton').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
   alert(url);
   $('#test').val(url);

<input type='text' name='image_big' size='58' id='test' />

Comment: maybe val(url) is referring to something else? What is url referring to exactly?

Comment: function afterSuccess(url) - your missing the url parameter in afterSuccess.
Url is just the data you get  from the ajax call. It is a parameter of the jquery ajax success function and you could call it "data", "msg" or whatever.